# Trouble adding UIBarButtonItem to self.toolbarItems

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(updateSites:)];

self.toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:refreshButton,nil];
```

No compile errors. just doesn't show up

This is in my viewDidLoad of one of my viewcontrollers which has previously been pushed on the navigationController stack

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarItems:[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:refreshButton,nil] autorelease]];
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference =\

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
[ refreshButton sizeToFit ]
```

before adding to the toolbar?

also, you will leak the array you are setting on self.toolbarItems unless you release it later. Use

```
[ NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshButton, nil ]
```

instead?

Comment: there is no sizeToFit in UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: you're right. you should call that on the view inside the item--although that might only work for a custom view.